# How to find a record that is not visible in the first pagination with Capybara

Tags: ruby, capybara

Friends, I have a big problem. If I register a record and the amount is greater than the one shown in the list, it is saved in another pagination. Capybara is only finding if the record is visible and on the first pagination. How do I search for this record if there are multiple paginations?

```
**I'm using this:** 
    def cad_diametro_material_active
    input_cod.send_keys('aut_Server_AL')
    input_order.send_keys('1')
    @ger_material_active = 'automation_Server_ALUMINIO_ACTIVE'+ rand(1..99).to_s
    input_description.send_keys(@ger_material_active)
    btn_insert.click
    find("td", text: @ger_material_active).click 
 **#The query was finding the record, but as the record moved to the other pagination it can't find it anymore. It seems that capybara only finds it when it is visible on the screen**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capybara tests what the user would see - if the item isn't visible on the screen then Capybara won't "see" it because a user wouldn't.  Therefore you need to do what a user would do, click whatever on the screen moves them to the next page of records.  As a tester you should control the test data and know that the record will be showing on the first or second (or third) page of results being shown, and write your test accordingly.  You don't show the HTML of your page so it's not possible to tell you exactly what you should be clicking on.

Also, stop using `send_keys` for everything -- when you have normal HTML input type elements use `fill_in` or `set` before opting for `send_keys`

Comment: What a pity. What if you use a While to scan all pages looking for these records

Comment: Thomas, I have a question. If the record is on the first page the button to go to the next page is disabled. How do I update this logic you taught me so if the record is found it doesn't enter this loop?